# Is it possible to download nature as a magazine?

Tags: publications, journals, online-resource

As i just want to skim over the latest articles in nature photonics, I was wondering if there is anyway to download all of the current issue as a single file (just as when one downloads Scientific American, even though these are very different publications). Still, there should be a way to download all of the current issue at once. Does anyone know if it's possible; if so, how?

Comment: The question is: how much money (US$ or € or Indian  ₹) can you afford paying for that?

Comment: My university has a suscription so I can download the articles, I was just wondering if everything could be download in a single click, like a magazine

Comment: A possibility is to use a recursive command-line downloader. Both [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) and [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) (or [Qt](http://qt.io/), with a few more source code of your own) come to mind, an both are open source software

Comment: Don't go that way. Site is authenticated and has antibot features

Answer (score 4):

Scientific American is a very different type of journal, in fact it more a "magazine" than a peer-reviewed academic journal like Nature.

Nature (and almost all other paid-subscription academic journals) does not want people downloading large numbers of articles at a time, even if they are doing it legally (with a paid subscription, such as yourself). This is because people who download ***so many*** articles at a time, are usually trying to do it for some reason that goes against the goals of the company printing the journal (in this case Nature Publishing Group). For example, people who download 100s of academic journal articles in one day, might be trying to create a repository of articles online for free access somewhere else on the internet or on PirateBay, or to sell the articles for $3 each instead of the $30 that nature usually charges.

On this question you have put a bounty containing the message:

> I really need to find a way to download it

Which begs the question: Why is it that you *need* to download an entire issue of a journal all at once? I do not know anyone that has such a wide breadth of scientific knowledge, that they can understand every article in one issue of Nature. I think the reason why 8 months have passed without any answer to this question, is that Nature ***also*** does not see any good reason why someone would want to do this, that would not go against the goals of the company, which are to make a profit.

If you are not planning to do anything illegal, the best solution for you is probably to use an automation software such as AutoIT (if using Windows), or to use command-line tools like `curl` or `wget` (if using Linux), and then combine the PDFs by dragging and dropping them into a PDF merging software like the one offered with [Small PDF](https://smallpdf.com/merge-pdf).

Comment: Thank you , I guess I didn't frame why I wanted to do it correctly , all i want it was to skim over the articles in a single file so I can see what people are up to, It seems like to much work to download them like that though , so now i just skim over the articles online

Comment: @GerardoSuarez Thanks for the clarification. Have you figured out how to skim through  the abstracts online?

Comment: I'm downloading all papers in the journal. I prefer they do not know what I'm interested in, until I submit a work.

Comment: You realize that Nature is also a "magazine", including editorials, news, opinion pieces and even book reviews, only with some research articles mixed in? There is even a surprisingly cheap print version including all the articles, ready to to be leafed through every week.

Answer (score 4):

Using the website, you can easily browse different issues using the following link:

https://www.nature.com/nphoton/volumes/14/issues/6

There is a menu like this on top:

```
<< Previous Issue | Volume 14 | Next Issue >>
```

which allows you to skim through issues and articles easily.

All articles will show a short abstract, and if you click on the titles, you can instantly see full-text and an option to download the PDF files.

To get an overview over the different volumes (years), use the following entry point:

https://www.nature.com/nphoton/volumes

Comment: And yet you have to download each separately, and put them togheter manually, there is nothing like a PDF version of the paper issue that Is delivered to home.